# Android Client for Powershell remote scripting?

Tags: android, scripting, powershell, client, powershell-remoting

Anyone know of a good client for Powershell remote scripting on a local network?

I understand WinRM is required on the client to enable remote scripting.

WinRM is "The Windows Remote Management (WinRM) is the Microsoft implementation of WS-Management Protocol, a standard Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP)-based, firewall-friendly protocol that allows hardware and operating systems, from different vendors, to interoperate." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426(v=vs.85).aspx

If a WinRM client is not available for Android but a WS-Management Protocol client is, can you use the latter for remote scripting?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but this might work.

http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/

If I understand it you would run this on the Windows server, then you can connect via any SSH client to it and get a PowerShell session.

Answer (score 0):

You will need PowerShell on the client to use PowerShell remoting.  However, you can launch PowerShell commands on the server using a WinRM client.  I can't find the article I read on that, I'll try to post it later.

I don't know about using any WS-Management compliant client.